# Explain TitanDB 1.0.0 Architecture vs OrientDB architecture?

Tags: orientdb, titan

I have to compare and contrast between them. So any one can explain it or give any reference?

Comment: You should refer to the documentation. If there is anything you do not understand then you should ask for a more concise clarification. As it stands your question will not get that much attention as it is very broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few differences between OrientDB and Titan.

1. Data Models

   OrientDB is a multi-model database - it claims to support both document (like mongodb) and graph formats (like Titan) in one database. [OrientDB Multi-model](http://orientdb.com/why-orientdb/)

   Titan is a single-model database - it claims to store graph data.
2. Storage Fromat

   OrientDB uses a custom storage format on disk. [OrientDB Storage](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Storages.html)

   Titan uses one of 3 types of external databases to store data. It uses a customized serialization process to store data in the database. [Titan Storage Backends](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/storage-backends.html)
3. Distributed Architecture

   OrientDB uses a memory grid called Hazelcast to achieve a distributed deployment. [OrientDB in distributed mode](https://hazelcast.com/resources/orientdb-hazelcast-memory-distributed-graph-database/)

   Titan uses the underlying data store (HBase or Cassandra) to achieve a distributed architecture.  HBase uses Zookeeper to coordinate. Cassandra uses its Gossip protocol to coordinate.
4. APIs

   OrientDB has both custom and TinkerPop Java APIs to access its data. [OrientDB Java APIs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Tutorial-Java.html)

   Titan exclusively uses TinkerPop APIs for data access. (From the Titan documentation: Native support for the popular property graph data model exposed by TinkerPop.  Native support for the graph traversal language Gremlin.)

Answer (score 0):

Both products offer online documentation: [Titan 1.0.0](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/) and [OrientDB 2.1.X](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/index.html)

Comment: yeah im new to it and i didn't understand alot from the documentation